# Having a macro use a global variable that can change dynamically

Tags: macros, conditionals, variable

Suppose I have a preamble that looks like this:

```
\newif\ifShowThings
\ShowThingstrue

\newcommand{\showcommand}[1]{
\ifShowThings
#1 % if the variable is true, then just print the argument, otherwise do nothing
\fi
}
```

If I write the preamble like this, then `\showcommand{...}` is be defined once and for all, depending on the value I give to `ShowThings` at the start.

What I want is to be able to change the value of `ShowThings` inside my document, so that \showcommand{...} behaves differently depending on where it is called. How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If you do `\ShowThingstrue` you set the conditional to true, and `\ShowThingsfalse` to false, so the outcome of the command will change... Is that it?

Comment: Also, use the `\else` in `\showcommand` definition *if* you want to do  something in case `ShowThings` is false.

Answer (score 1):

Your statement is incorrect. as you have defined it `\showcommands` checks the value of `\ifShowthings` every time it is used, it does not check it at the point of definition (`\ifShowthings` need not even be defined at the point that `\showcommands` is defined.)

Beware of white space though, your current definition always insertes a space token at the beginning.

```
\newcommand{\showcommand}[1]{%
\ifShowThings
#1 % if the variable is true, then just print the argument, otherwise do nothing
\fi
}
```

then you can use `\ShowThingstrue` or `\ShowThingsfalse` within the document.

Comment: I am sorry David, you are right this works. I thought I was describing the content of my TeX file, but in fact what my file contains is different. So this means I have spotted the problem, many thanks!